# if a div is 100% width by default

Tags: html

If a `div` is 100% width, should I still put in `width: 100%;`? I look at a lot of code and it's always in there even though by default a `div` is 100%.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, doing so can actually cause problems. `100%` is not the same as `auto`. `width` refers to the width of the content, excluding borders, padding and margins. `auto` automatically computes the width such that the total width of the div fits the parent, but setting `100%` will force the content alone to 100%, meaning the padding etc. will stick out of the div, making it larger than the parent.

[See this for an example](http://jsbin.com/otuga4/2)

Comment: so setting the 'width' to 'auto' would be better?

Comment: Yes, but that's the default anyway.

Comment: 13 years later and this answer taught me something really important. Just amazing

Comment: example link is dead

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the children elements will adapt themselfs with procentual values if their parent doesn't have a width attribute. Otherwise it's just semantic and good practice to put width: 100%; if the div is supposed to span 100% of it's parent container.

Answer (score 0):

nope, pretty useless I think to give it a 100% width unless you have a background-color or image or something in this div.