# Curious width 100% CSS problem

Tags: css, browser, width, overflow

I just realized that every browsers seem to have a curious render problem.

This is the test case: http://jsfiddle.net/cKNQD/

**1**. Please scale your browser until the bottom scrollbar appears.

**2**. Then scroll to the very right.

You will see, that the #header will not longer have a 100% width. The problem
seems to be the .wrapper inside. I need that wrapper to limit the dimension
of the #headers content.

Solution welcome.

Comment: This isn't a render problem; the browsers are following the spec. The width of #header is 100%, which is the width of the browser window. When you make `.wrapper` wider than 100%, it overflows from `#header`. You can either set a `min-width` as suggested, or an exact `width`, or set `overflow: hidden` to hide the overflow (but that's probably not what you want).

Comment: the very best solution should be to add a min-width style to the body or 100% container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `min-width: 980px;` to the header.

See [updated fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/cKNQD/9/).

Tested on Win7 in IE7, IE8, IE9, Opera 11.50, Safari 5.0.5, FF 6.0, Chrome 13.0.

Comment: Are you sure? Whatever I am horizontally scrolling, the upper 100px are all gray over the complete width of the window.

Comment: This makes `#header` widen to include `.wrapper`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: ah okay, i added it to the wrapper and not header... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Width of #header is not defined, so it is not 100%, it is "[auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906573/if-a-div-is-100-width-by-default)".

Maybe you should remove "width: 600px" from .foo class?

Comment: block elements are 100% by default^^ ... and no .foo ist just an example for content.