# adding an background to a div without having text?

Tags: html, css

im trying to make an html element have a background image using css, but the background doesn't without having text for example.

CSSS -

```
#box {

  background url(.....)


}
```

HTML -

```
 <div id="box">something</div> // this works bu it shows the text

 <div id="box"></div>          // this is what i want not text just the background url from #box
```

thanks :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because the div is 0x0px. Give it a height and a width.

Answer (score 1):

Set a width and height on the div.
Example:
HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
  background: url(path/to/image.png);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div has an `auto` height by default. The reason you are only seeing the background when text is entered into the `div` is because the `auto` height is being increased from `0px` to whatever height is now required now there is text in place.

Therefore if you need a fixed height, you need to set a `height` property in your CSS:

```
#box
{
   background: url(.....);
   height:100px;
}
```

You don't need to set a width as this will automatically be `auto` width [by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3906762/370103).